# program not detecting null terminating character when input through function

Tags: c, input, null, fgets

I am trying to find the length of the input string using `fgets` and `strlen` but I have came across some issues where the null terminating character is unable to be detected.

By empty input string I mean just pressing enter without entering anything.

I have used `strlen` on the input of empty string and outputs `1` where is should be `0`.

```
int func(char *input) {
    if (input[0] == '\0')
        printf("null detected\n");
    else
        printf("null not detected\n");

    printf("len: %lu", strlen(input));
}


int main() {
    char input[256];
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    func(input);
    return 0;
}
```

output: `null not detected`

correct output: `null detected`

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) of `fgets`: the `\n` (newline character) is stored by fgets, so if you just press the Enter key, the content of the buffer will be `"\n"`, that is a single newline character followed by a null character.

Answer (score 0):

The function `fgets` can append the entered string with the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter if the destination character array has enough space to accommodate it.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
> characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
> the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null
> character is written immediately after the last character read into
> the array.

So in your case when you just pressed the Enter key the array `input` looks like

```
{ '\n', '\0' }
```

So `input[0]` is not equal to `'\0'`. `input[0]` will be equal to `'\n'`.

If you declare the array like

```
char input[1];
```

and will press at once the Enter key when entering a string then indeed `input[0]` will be equal to `'\0'` because the destination array does not have a space to store the new line character `'\n'`.

If you want to remove the new line character from an entered string you can write for example

```
input[ strcspn( input, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```